# Set core.autocrlf for bitbucket pipelines

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to use (cloud) bitbucket's pipelines to automatically build my angular app. One of the tslint settings we have in our project is to enforce that [line breaks are CRLF](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/linebreak-style/).

However, when I try to do a build with pipelines, we get a tslint error for every single line of our code saying that it expected line endings to be CRLF.

Since we don't see that anywhere else on any of our developer's computers, I am guessing that pipelines itself has their `git config core.autocrlf` set to `false`.

What can I specify in my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` to tell pipelines to not mess with my line endings?

Just specifying the git config setting in the build step won't work because by the time it executes my scripts, it has already pulled the code from source control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this will work, but not certain if its the best way...

Adding a `.gitattributes` file with `*.ts text eol=crlf` included should cause BitBucket to keep all ts files with crlf line endings

Although with that setting, your tslint rule would be fully redundant?  I would question if your tslint rule is already redundant (if you were to have `* text=auto` and `*.ts text` in the `.gitattributes` file) and perhaps you should consider ignoring that rule?  (if git recognizes it as a text file, it will convert the line endings based on the operating system, is there a reason you'd want your TypeScript files to have crlf on linux/mac?)

https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Comment: already had this in .gitattributes: `text eol=crlf`. I think `ng new` puts that there by default.

Comment: Do you have `*.ts text` in there as well?  That will make certain that git will decide ts files are text

Comment: Hey, it works if you specify *.ts! Weird that it needs that. Thanks!